# retrieving time from an ntp server behind an http proxy using Java

Tags: java, proxy, ntp

I'm using the [Apache Commons Net TimeTCPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/time/TimeTCPClient.html) to retrieve the current time from a time server. I'm trying to get this work on a corporate network that is using an (authenticated) http proxy server. I'm detecting the proxy with the [Proxy Vole](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) library.
Unfortunately it seems that [Java doesn't support http proxies](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6370908) until Java 8?? I always get the `java.net.SocketException: Unknown proxy type: HTTP` exception.

How can I retrieve the current time from an ntp server when behind an http proxy?

**Edit:** The problem seems to be that the Proxy Vole library uses the [ProxySelector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) class, which always causes the SocketException. It doesn't matter if I use ntp or http, as long as the ProxySelector by Vole is set, this problem occurs.

Comment: I have found a workaround, asking time over http: http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now. I'd still like to know however if there is way to do this with NTP

Answer (score 0):

The corporate proxy is almost certainly just proxying HTTP traffic (port 80 & 443).

NTP uses port 123, which is probably blocked by the company firewall.  Which will be why you are getting the SocketException.

Comment: No, the exception is thrown because a SocksSocketImpl class has been created somewhere when configuring the proxy, and the proxy is of type HTTP. According to the bug I linked the Socket(Proxy) constructor only handles DIRECT and SOCKS proxy types.

Answer (score 0):

If port 123 over UDP is being blocked then you won't be able to retrieve the NTP datagram packet. However, you still have a couple of options.

One solution is to use a NTP server within your corporate firewall if one is available. You would need to contact your system administrator or IT department.

You could also make a HTTP connection to a public web site; e.g. http://www.ntp.org/, and fetch the remote clock time by extracting the value of the date HTTP header.

The HTTP headers would be as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 07 Mar 2014 02:36:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Server: Apache
```

The *Date* HTTP header provides the clock time of that remote server to the second resolution which you could convert to a long value as milliseconds since the standard epoch (1-Jan-1970).

Here's snippet of code to fetch a URL and convert date header to Java Date instance:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.ntp.org/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
}
long dateTime = conn.getHeaderFieldDate("Date", 0);
if (dateTime > 0) {
    Date receiveTime = new Date(dateTime);
    // do something with remote timestamp
}
```

If behind a firewall, you either have to include a java.net.Proxy argument in url.openConnection(proxy) call or set proxy in JVM System properties; e.g. System.setProperty("http.proxyHost" ,"myproxy.org"), etc.